# Syntax error when using pointers through function calling and parameters in C

Tags: c

I am getting a syntax error when trying to allocate space for a multidimensional matrix. I am new to coding in C, so anything will help. The error occurs when trying to access the matrix structure elements in the read_matrix function. The syntax error is "expression must have struct or union type". Where the error is produced is commented out in the read_matrix function.

```
typedef struct {

int *elements;
int rows;
int columns;

} matrix;

void main() {

matrix a, b, c;

void read_matrix(matrix *);
void deallocate(matrix *);
void print(matrix);
matrix add(matrix, matrix);
matrix subtract(matrix, matrix);
matrix multiply(matrix, matrix);

read_matrix(&a);
read_matrix(&b);

c = add(a, b);

deallocate(&c);
c = subtract(a, b);

deallocate(&c);
c = multiply(a, b);

}

void read_matrix(matrix *z) {

int d1, d2, i, x, y, val;

printf("What is the first dimension of the array? ");
scanf("%d", &d1);

printf("What is the second dimension of the array? ");
scanf("%d", &d2);

*z.elements = (int *)calloc(d2, sizeof(int));
*z.rows = d1;
*z.columns = d2;        
    /* error here. It isn't letting me access the 
      elements/rows/columns of the matrix */

/* additional code below here */
}
```

Comment: And the syntax error is? (verbatim text please)

Comment: Does not look like C# at all... Please check name of language written on your textbook.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov OP already stated it's c. I removed the irrelevant tags.

Comment: The syntax error is - "expression must have struct or union type". Sorry

Comment: First, don't add vital info as a comment. Edit your question and add it to the question. Second, also add which line of code produces that error. We're not mind readers here.

Comment: @CareyGregory Fixed. Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow. Thanks for the advice

Comment: The right syntax is `z->rows` when `z` is a pointer and `z.rows` when `z` is a variable.

Comment: Side-note: You're allocating space for `columns` items, but surely you want to allocate `rows * columns` worth of space?

Answer (score 1):

Operator `.` has higher precedence than unary operator `*`, which means that if you want to access struct members through a pointer `z` using `*`-and-`.` combination, you have to use parentheses. It your case it should be

```
(*z).elements = ...
```

Alternatively you can use `->` operator

```
z->elements = ...
```

And it is supposed to be `int main()`, not `void main()`

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem!

Comment: @M. Diet: Your code suffers from other problems as well. I don't see how `d1` affects memory allocation for the matrix. It doesn't actually. That appears to be wrong, since memory allocation for a matrix normally depends on both sizes of the matrix.

Comment: Yes, I was made aware of that in the above comments as well. Thank you for the advice!